# Use ilike any() with escape character

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

In PostgreSQL you can do a case insensitive query with `ILIKE`:

```
select * from test where value ilike 'half is 50$%' escape '$'
```

And you can query multiple values at once by combining `ILIKE` with `ANY()`

```
select * from test where value ilike any(array['half is 50%', 'fifth is 20%'])
```

The query above will match `'Fifth is 2019'`, which I do not want, but when I try to use `ILIKE` and `ANY()` with an escape character I get a syntax error.

Am I missing something stupid, or is this simply not supported? If not, is there another way to query in a case insensitive way with multiple values at once?

**EDIT:** To clarify, the query will accept parameters through JDBC, so the actual SQL will look something like

```
select * from test where value ilike any(?) escape '$'
```

This is why I'm looking make % and _ from the user input be interpreted as literals.

Comment: in your second example with `any()`, are you still looking to escape the `%`?

Comment: @richyen Yes. I've made some edits to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ESCAPE` clause in `ILIKE` refers only to literals and does not apply to expressions. You should use a backslash, or if not possible, you can try:

```
with test(value) as (
values 
    ('half is 50%'),
    ('half is 50x'),
    ('fifth is 20%'),
    ('fifth is 2000')
)

select * 
from test
where value ilike any(select replace(unnest(array['half is 50$%', 'fifth is 20$%']), '$', '\'))

    value     
--------------
 half is 50%
 fifth is 20%
(2 rows)
```

Looks a bit clumsy but works well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize backslash is used by default if you don't specify an escape character in the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To match them as raw strings, you may use the `~*` operator for insensitive match.

```
knayak=# select 'Half is 50%' ~* any(array['half is 50%', 'fifth is 20%'])
knayak-# ;
 ?column?
----------
 t            --True
(1 row)

knayak=# select 'fifth is 20' ~* any(array['half is 50%', 'fifth is 20%']);
 ?column?
----------
 f             --False
(1 row)
```

If you wish to escape the right hand operands of `ilike` use "escape" string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote

```
knayak=# select 'Half is 50%' ilike any(array[E'half is 50\\%', E'half is 20\\%'])
knayak-# ;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=51b9930177d6a5aa984bd0d0959b0480)

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my situation. Using ```~*``` will match using regex, so I'd have to escape dots and such instead. Your second example is intriguing, but I'm unsure of how E could be added infront of parameters.